# Python - Problem with variables

Tags: python, variables

sorry if this is an obvious question, but I am relatively new to python and am completely stumped at the moment. I am having difficulty getting my variables to work the way I want them too in a program I am working on.

Here is an example I quickly made to showcase my problem:

```
life = 200

def example(dudeHP):
    dudeHP = dudeHP - 75
    print (dudeHP)

example(life)
print (life) #output is 200, but I want it to be 125
```

As you can see, I am trying to get the value of the global variable "life" to change inside the def example codeblock with dudeHP (which would be a local variable if I am not mistaken?)

Is this viable? Is there a better way to accomplish this? Or am I doing it all wrong? Thankyou in advance :)

Comment: Python does not support call-by-reference, only call-by-value. You passed *a copy* of '200' to `example()` and that's what it subtracted '75' from, not from `life`.

Comment: @Peter No. Python doesn't make copies like that. He passed a reference, the he pointed the name `dudehp` at a new value (125) without ever re-pointing or changing `life` or the value it points to.

Comment: @agf It doesn't point ``dudehp`` to a new value, but to a new **object**. In fact, AFAI have understood, the identifier ``dudehp`` is binded to a kind of pointer in the symbol table (in Python, the word 'reference' is preferred, I don't know why) , and this binded association doesn't change. The only thing that changes is the value in the reference associated with the ``dudehp``, which is the address of the object at which the identifier indirectly points to. Then ``dudehp=dudehp-75`` triggers such a changement of address in the pointer associated,but not of the association in the symbol table

Comment: That said, as underlined by others, ``dudehp`` is a local identifier that exists only in the function. When the interpreter goes out of the function this identifier and its association in the symbol table disappear from memory. AFAIU

Comment: @agf No, it isn't appropriate to use them synonymously. Computer science is hard enough to undertsand to make effort to reduce the confusions and ambiguities; **Every object has an identity, a type and a value.** (http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types) The identity is the address in the pointer that points to the object, it's not a part of the object. But, as far as I have understood, the type is an intimate characteristic of the object, constituing it inseparately with the value. Object = type + value. So value != object. That's how I see it

Comment: @agf No copy of the object 200, that is to say something like (type==int,value==200), is created and passed as argument to the function, I agree with that. But you must explain what you call ``dudehp`` when you say that ``dudehp`` changes. For me, the identifier (that is to say the name) **dudehp** doesn't change; the object 200 no more changes; a new object of type int and value 125  is created in RAM at a different location than the 200's location, and the value of the pointer associated with the identifier **dudehp** is modified to make the pointer pointing to the new object 125

Comment: @agf In a way, I make a difference between **dudehp** and ``dudehp``. The former is a name, a sequence of characters, associated with a pointer , the association lies in the symbol table. The latter is a kind of implied shortcut to designate the object pointed by the pointer. There is no symbolism to designate the pointer, AFAIK; only its value can be repreented and obtained with ``id(dudehp)``

Comment: @agf _He said "a copy of '200'", not "a copy of the object with value '200'"._ Yes, and everybody who knows Python well understands that he employs a shortcut to say "the object of value 200". In Python, saying "200" cannot mean anything else, since _all is object_. That doesn't justify why it would be correct to employ "value" instead of "object" in the context of this programming's problem , as far as someone perceives the technical difference between these two terms.

Comment: @agf  By the way, writing _a copy of '200' .... that's what Python subtracted '75' from_  betrays that Peter misunderstands the underlying mechanisms, and you should have rectified this point too.

Comment: @agf Your correction was good concerning its general idea and it's true that it is understandable. What I criticize is just the confusion between value and object, that doesn't gives good understanding to a newbie.

Comment: @agf  Despite you pretend that it has nothing to do with the subject, the fact is that Peter alludes to what is passed to the function (an object according to him), and you employ the term "reference". The matter is  really about objects and references. No ? Hence  I consider it's better to give plain clarity to the questioner concerning the underlying mechanisms, that's the opportunity for him to understand something well, not acquiring a vague notion that something happens concerning vague entities incorrectly named.

Comment: @agf _"value" is frequently used instead of "object" with things like numbers and strings that people often think of as they exist outside of computing _  That's right and justified when we think about the values as concepts implied in mental operations. I don't pretend that everybody in everyday life should employs "object" instead of "value". But if we speak about a concrete mechanism implied in a computer's operation, then the only correct way is to employ the correct unambiguous terms. And you can't deny that the subject is really concerning concrete mechanisms in the memory of a computer.

Comment: @agf _I don't think it's useful to draw a distinction between the identifier and it's pointer_ Arf. We have not to draw such a distinction, the fact is that they ARE distinct. Otherwise, what would be the symbol table ?

Comment: @agf OK. I stop. Anyway I have nothing else to say. In fact I write all this in the intention for the newbie questioner, to make him understand important points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all, you'll probably want to write an class or something to organize all this at some point. Modifying global variables from within functions or methods is usually considered a bad idea.

What you might want to try is this:

```
life = 200

def example(x):
    return x - 75

life = example(life)
```

Of course in this case the operation of subtraction is so trivial that you don't need to encapsulate it in a function.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, the question is not Python3 specific unless a newcomer gets stumped by the title. It is a general Python language question.

You have to understand the scope and the nature of the variables in Python. Variables are just names to hold certain values and their life is within the scope of the block they are defined it, although the inner scope variable can access the variable from the outer scope. The function you have defined has its own scope and it's own stack to maintain and you are passing a copy of the variable to that function.

The best way to deal with this is return value from the function as pointed out in another answer.

Having said that, if you really want to access variable in a global manner, you could do like this.

```
a = 200

def example(b):
    global a
    a = a - 25

example(a)
print a
```

But this is **frowned upon** and not a good style. There is also a trick which you are use, but that goes beyond the beginner level and it goes like this.
a = [200]

```
def example(a):
    a[0] = a[0] - 25

example(a)
print a[0]
```

You can **easily make mistakes** you if adopt this way,

**But the correct way to go about this is still:**

```
a = 200

def example(b):
    return b - 25

print example(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Further to Ned Batchelders and Kristoff's hints and suggestions to use a class, this is a way you could do that:

```
class Dude:
    def __init__(self, hp=200):
        self.hp = hp

    def eat(self):
        self.hp = self.hp + 25

def example(dude):
    dude.hp -= 75

hero = Dude()
example(hero)
hero.eat()
print(hero.hp)   # 150
```

Unless you have a good reason why `example` should be a stand-alone function, you should make it a method of `Dude` like `eat`, since `example` clearly acts on and in a sense *belongs* to an object of the class `Dude`.

Answer (score 0):

In your function, the name `dudeHP` is local to the function.  When you change it, you are only changing the local name, you cannot affect the value of the name passed in.

You can either make the integer be an element of a container that you pass in, so that you can change the container, or you can return the value from the function.

Answer (score 0):

Since `dudehp` is having local scope in that function it doesn't have life outside that function. So, using `dudehp` to update life is illegal you can do this by using a global keyword or returing the value as others have  mentioned... hope this explanation is useful and any corrections to this will be accepted.